# How to measure time it took an application to load all used assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, webforms

I'm trying to find out why a big WebForms application is starting up slowly (sometimes 2+ minutes). 
I suspect slow start has to do with lots of assemblies it loads up (about 50 NuGet packages + compiled ASPX pages), but I'm not sure. How do I measure how much time it took the CLR to load all assemblies? 
I tried both dotTrace and ants profiler, haven't found that metric. 
I heard about [profiling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/), but it's my understanding it's native only - and I'm far from C++ expert.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to view logs that show you assemblies loading and binding, the tool you are looking for is [fusion logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer). Normally you use Fusion to log bind failures, but you can set it to "Log all binds to disk" to log everything. Turn those on and inspect the timestamps to see if anything is taking a long time to load.

Comment: I see one timestamp - so it doesn't say how long it took to load an assembly. May be I'm missing something?

Comment: my bad - found the second one